# Mac OS X Snow Leopard 403 Forbidden

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, localhost, apache-http-server

After an update to my computer my server on Snow Leopard has become unstable. I continually get Forbidden 403 issues on every page that I try to access. I can upload my apache log files...just not sure where they are stored on Mac. Working on a project and need to get this rectified asap so any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
/etc/apache2/users/whatever.conf
```

to make sure they didn't get moved or reset? Something broad like this has changed to cause 403 on all the pages.

Answer (score 1):

Your starting point should, of course be checking the logs.

On OS X the Apache logs can be found in:

```
/var/log/apache2
```

It would be my bet that there is a permission problem on a file or perhaps a missing folder, but a check of `/var/log/apache2/error_log` should give you the clues you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just had to deal with that.  Here is the seminal link on that.

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied

> In order to serve files, Apache must have the proper permission granted by the operating system to access those files. In particular, the User or Group specified in httpd.conf **must be able to read all files that will be served and search the directory containing those files, along with all parent directories up to the root of the filesystem.**